# Vagrant + CentOS 7 - Apache fails to start, I don't see an error

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, vagrant, apache-virtualhost

I'm spending some time trying to provision a Vagrant box running from a CentOS 7 base box.

After a fresh install of Apache, I am able to hit the server over `http` and restart the server, but as soon as I add virtual hosts for `https` I encounter errors. This is an example of my virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.example.com/web
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.example.com/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.example.com/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    # Admin email, Servername, and ailases
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName example.example.com

    #Index file and document root
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.example.com/web

    #SSL certs
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/example.example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/example.example.com.key

    #Log locations
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/example.example.com/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/example.example.com/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is what I get when I run `apachectl restart`:

```
Job for httpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status httpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

So naturally, I do what I'm told and run `systemctl status httpd.service`, with the following output:

```
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2015-07-29 00:56:20 UTC; 40s ago
  Process: 21318 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 21317 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 21317 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Total requests: 11; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"

Jul 29 00:56:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jul 29 00:56:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 29 00:56:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jul 29 00:56:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
```

I don't see any actual errors, it just fails.

EDIT: My `apachectl -t` output was requested:

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of `apachectl configtest`?

Comment: @eyoung100 yup, it's at the bottom